# Как определить с какой формы на сервлет пришли данные?

Tags: java, servlet

У меня несколько форм которые отдают данные в метод `doPost` и мне надо определить внутри самого метода `doPost` от какой формы пришли данные.

```
// тут id
<form method="POST" action="UserServlet">
    <input type="number" name="id"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

// а тут name
<form method="POST" action="UserServlet">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    req.?????() //Вот тут как-то определить от какой формы пришло

}
```

Как мне узнать от какой формы пришли данные если их несколько в одном `jsp`.

И если формы на разных `jsp` но используют один `doPost`?

Comment: запилите в форму скрытое поле с идентификатором формы если хотите отслеживать

Comment: Почему не использовать несколько сервлетов, если формы на разных jsp?

Comment: Можно по разным путям формы отправлять.

Comment: кстати да...у Вас же разные поля в формах..они по смыслу разные ведь?

Comment: @Михаил Ребров да они разные.

Comment: @Alex78191 да по поводу разных сервлетов это точно, но у меня задание в котором сказано про 1 так что я так и делаю. А что значит отправлять по разным путям? Это как?

Comment: @Павел action разный задать.

Comment: @Alex78191 для этого надо несколько сервлетов разных а у меня он 1,  к сожалению...

Comment: @Павел , если сервлет должен быть один, то делайте поля с идентификатором формы, по нему сможете и понять какие поля вытягивать

Comment: @Alex78191 а как мне внутри doPost получить этот идентификатор?

Comment: Вам же писали `в переданном HttpServletRequest есть несколько методов (getRequestURI(), getPathInfo()), которые позволяют получить запрошенный путь `

Comment: @Павел можно примапить сервлет ко всем url, начинающимся с определенной строки https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972914/wildcard-path-for-servlet

Comment: @Alex78191 анатациями меня просили не мапить. У меня `getRequestURI` возвращает `"имя_сервлета+RequestURI"` как я из этого могу получить айдишник формы? А getPathInfo - null возвращает...

Comment: @Павел ну мапьте через web.xml.

Comment: @Павел про id формы не я говорил.

Comment: См. коменты к ответу bsuart-а

Comment: @Alex78191 да пардон.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Добавить в форму скрытое поле `<input type="hidden" name="command" value="addUser"/>`
2. Извлекать в контроллере command и выполнять в зависимости от его значения какие либо действия

   ```
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
       processRequest(request, response);
   }

   @Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
       processRequest(request, response);
   }

   private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
     String nameCommand = request.getParameter("command");
   }
   ```

Comment: Можно кнопкам submit назначить разные value. И таким образом обойтись без лишних полей.

Comment: Или заметить, что у одной формы есть поле name, а у другой его нет. Зато у другой есть id, а у первой нет. Таким образом тоже можно догадаться какая форма поступила на сервер

Comment: @Sergey а как мне указать когда я вызову `request.getParameter("value");` что мне нужен `value` именно от кнопки на форме, на странице могут еще много всяких `value` атрибутов появиться у разных элементов... Как мне именно этот `value` выделить?

Comment: @Павел для начала изучи как HTTP запросы выполняться.

Comment: @Alex78191 так у меня только данная форма использует `doPost` и отправляет только инпуты, а вся остальная страница тут вообще не при чем... И какие там у кого атрибуты мне вообще все равно... Правильно?

Comment: @Павел правильно, это параметры запроса